# ¿Como puedo mandar un objeto en un Ngmodel?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Este es mi codigo:

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar.." 
  id="sku_select" 
  aria-label="number"
  matInput [formControl]="myControl" 
  [matAutocomplete]="auto"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"
  (change)="changeClient($event.value)">
       <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let datos of filteredOptions | async" 
          [value]="datos.campo_1">{{datos.campo_1}}
        </mat-option>
```

Como se pueden dar cuenta tengo un tipado llamado Formulario donde declaro `campo_1, campo_2 y campo_3`, lo que quiero es que mi `NgModel` pueda obtener el `campo_2`, pero sin tener que cambiar el valor de mi `mat-option` ya que lo deseo colocar en otro input que es el siguiente:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control"
     [(ngModel)]="resume.socialProfile"
     name="socialProfile" placeholder="Social Profile "
     [value]="selectedValue.campo_2">
 </div>
```

Se que lo que estoy haciendo esta completamente erroneo, puesto que mi `Ngmodel` almacena unicamente el valor de mi `mat-option`, pero hay alguna manera en la que pueda guardar el `campo_2`? por ejemplo, en mi `mat-option` tengo el `campo_1 = 78` (el cual se muestra al momento de seleccionar, pero tambien esta el `campo_2`, ese `campo_2` es el que quiero establecer en el input **"Social Profile"** Espero y me haya explicado bien, muchas gracias a todos por leerme.

Answer (score 0):

Logre solucionar el problema, mi solución fue la siguiente:
En mi component.ts tengo una funcion que se encarga de filtrar los datos de un select, (mat-autocomplete) como esta funcion se encarga de filtrar los datos del select guiandose por el campo_1, cuando se tienen los resultados esta funcion retorna los 2 campos que hicieron match, para extraer el campo_2 inicio un bucle for, el valor lo asigno a una variable publica y esa la tengo vinculada con el input "Social Profile", este es el codigo de la funcion, espero que les sirva y no se rompan tanto la cabeza como lo hice yo, saludos a toda la comunidad stack Overflow!

```
  private _filter(value: string): Formulario[] {
const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
const datos_ = this.formularioDatos.filter(formularioDatos => formularioDatos.campo_1.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
console.log(datos_);
for(let elemento of datos_){
  const campo_2 = elemento.campo_2;
 this.campo_2_ = campo_2;
  console.log(elemento);
  //console.log(this.selectedValue);
}
```